# Infinite loop JavaRDD<String> spark 1.6

Tags: java, apache-spark

i'am trying to iterate a JavaRDD and find element by applying method which use this RDD and then i should delete is

here is my code:

---

```
items=input.map(x->{

        min=getMin(input);

        return min;


    })
    .filter(x ->  ! Domine(x, min));
```

but there is no result it seem an infinite loop 
how can i fix it 
thanks

Comment: What does `Domine` do? And it seems you should call `getMin()` outside the loop

Comment: Is the `min` in the `filter` the same as the `min` in the map? If so, it is not accessible from there.

Comment: You're referring to methods and fields hat you haven't posted: `getMin`, `Domine`, `min`. Also, a lambda passed to `map` that doesn't use its argument `x` at all cannot be good/useful.

Comment: @DinoPrašo yes it is the same min. i need to do like this how can i do it !

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn domine is a boolean method if x and min have different characteristics it return true

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to implementations like this one (same as Java8 streams, or Kotlin sequences) they are implemented in a lazy way, thus you need to perform a terminal operation, only then the work will be done.

So if you do a `filter` and end there - nothing will happen since you didn't perform any terminal operation. Do for example `first()`, `take(1)`, `forEach(...)` or any other terminal operation, you can find them [here.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the **very** vague description, i believe what you require would be something like the following, assuming that `input` is of type `JavaRDD<Row>`:

```
final Row min = input.min((row1, row2) -> {
    //  TODO: replace by some real comparator implementation
    Integer row1value = row1.getInt(row1.fieldIndex("fieldName"));
    Integer row2value = row2.getInt(row2.fieldIndex("fieldName"));

    return row1value.compareTo(row2value);
});

items = input.filter(row -> !Domine(row, min));
```

Sine Apache SPARK Transformations like `filter` are inherently lazy, to actually retrieve the value you would have to then write `List collectedValues = items.collect();` I would, however, strongly recommend that `.collect()` never actually goes into production since it can be very dangerous indeed.

Comment: i want while i have element in the input i find the min then i delete it and that seem to me for one time !!